# file.read() doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, function

So I'm new to programming and I'm making a zork-type game as extracurricular practice. And currently I'm trying to make a simple "load" function where python would extract the previously saved name and class of character.
The code is this:

```
print "Enter savefile name: " 
save1 = raw_input("> ") + ".py"
load_data = open(save1, "r")
data = load_data.read()
```

However it doesn't read the file. So if I'd write something like `print data` it would just skip the command, without any errors or anything really.

I've been looking at this stupid piece of code for ages and can't figure out what's the problem with it. Please help!

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the savefile name has ".py" at the end? Normally you'd use a ".txt" file or something for string storage since ".py" is intended for executable python scripts. In this case it won't make a functional difference, but maybe you're just getting the filename wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the file to make sure it has something in it?

Comment: It might also be that the file is not in the current working directory. Have you tried putting in the full path to double check?

Comment: It does have a .py on the end, but I did change it to .txt and altered the code accordingly and got the same result as before - it just ignores the "print data" command.

Comment: Does the `print` statement print a blank line (file was empty), or does it actually do nothing?

Comment: Yep, I checked countless number of times that it has something in it and made sure it was in the same directory.

Comment: And what does `print len(data)` display? `0`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 how do I find out which one it is? Sorry for the silly question but I can't tell the difference

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Indeed it is 0

Comment: Ergo, the file is empty.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You are correct. I don't know how I messed this one up.

Thank you, everybody, for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked at each stage that something is actually being returned. Try something like so:

```
if save1:
    print "save1 is correct"

if load_data:
    print "load_data is correct"

if data:
    print "data has a value"
```

Try these lines after your code block. This will help you identify where the error is, and once your problem is isolated you will be able to better search for what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I was a complete idiot and somehow missed that the file was empty.

Comment: Its cool, yeah, sometimes you just got to take a step back and do some sanity checks.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a text file with a custom name, if that's what you mean

```
sname=str(input("Enter savefile name: "))
fw=open(sname+'.txt', 'w')
fw.close()
```